# data visualization following glmm in lmer

Tags: data-visualization, lme4-nlme, glmm, lsmeans

Everything I know about glmms is from the internet, and after extensive searching, I haven't come across a good clearcut guide for **how to visualize your data in a way that is relevant to hypotheses and fits the model results**. Essentially, if you just plot means for various groups, that doesn't account for random effects. I am seeking confirmation that using the lsmeans package makes sense but also, what specifically I should plot from lsmeans.

Data available: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1qhq2qhwriotkRQUFYP1a_2oqBN_TQ37JhqOVFBis7Ds/edit?usp=sharing

Specifics of my data:

I studied the effect of four pollination treatments on the production of a specific type of flowers (CHFlwr). Size (BSD) and height (hgt) of plants may affect floral production so I included those in my models. There were max ~15 flowers per plant so I used Poisson errors, then followed with Tukey's post hoc using multcomp.

```
CHfoct<-glmer(POL$CHFlwr~Trtmt+(1|Hgt)+(1|BSD), family=poisson, data=POL)
multchoct<-glht(CHfoct, linfct = mcp(Trtmt = "Tukey" ))
```

Diagnostics plots seem normal (qqnorm plots/resid v fitted, etc).
Results as follow:

```
> CHfoct<-glmer(POL$CHFlwr~Trtmt+(1|Hgt)+(1|BSD), family=poisson, data=POL)
    > summary(CHfoct)
    Generalized linear mixed model fit by maximum likelihood (Laplace         Approximation) ['glmerMod']
     Family: poisson  ( log )
    Formula: POL$CHFlwr ~ Trtmt + (1 | Hgt) + (1 | BSD)
Data: POL

 AIC      BIC   logLik deviance df.resid 
 954.6    972.4   -471.3    942.6      138 

Scaled residuals: 
 Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
-2.5876 -0.5811 -0.0711  0.3527  3.2776 

Random effects:
 Groups Name        Variance Std.Dev.
 Hgt    (Intercept) 0.3415   0.5844  
 BSD    (Intercept) 0.1367   0.3698  
Number of obs: 144, groups:  Hgt, 103; BSD, 15

Fixed effects:
                       Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
(Intercept)              1.9717     0.1368  14.412   <2e-16 ***
TrtmtBagged              0.2486     0.1264   1.966   0.0492 *  
TrtmtOx_Supplemented    -0.1848     0.1250  -1.478   0.1393    
TrtmtSelf_Supplemented  -0.1406     0.1323  -1.063   0.2878    
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Correlation of Fixed Effects:
            (Intr) TrtmtB TrtO_S
TrtmtBagged -0.329              
TrtmtOx_Spp -0.202  0.308       
TrtmtSlf_Sp -0.253  0.425  0.275
> Anova(CHfoct)
Analysis of Deviance Table (Type II Wald chisquare tests)

 Response: POL$CHFlwr
            Chisq Df Pr(>Chisq)   
    Trtmt 11.747  3   0.008302 **

Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
> multchoct<-glht(CHfoct, linfct = mcp(Trtmt = "Tukey" ))
> summary(multchoct)

 Simultaneous Tests for General Linear Hypotheses

Multiple Comparisons of Means: Tukey Contrasts


Fit: glmer(formula = POL$CHFlwr ~ Trtmt + (1 | Hgt) + (1 | BSD), data = POL, 
 family = poisson)

Linear Hypotheses:
                                          Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)  
Bagged - Ambient_Pollinated == 0           0.24863    0.12644   1.966  0.1983  
Ox_Supplemented - Ambient_Pollinated == 0 -0.18477    0.12499  -1.478  0.4473  
Self_Supplemented - Ambient_Pollinated == -0.14059    0.13226  -1.063  0.7093  
Ox_Supplemented - Bagged == 0             -0.43340    0.14790  -2.930  0.0179*
Self_Supplemented - Bagged == 0           -0.38922    0.13882 -2.804   0.0257*
Self_Supplemented - Ox_Supplemented == 0   0.04418    0.15502   0.285   0.9918  
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
(Adjusted p values reported -- single-step method)
```

In the lsmeans package, I was able to get lsmeans for treatment but not a backtransformed value (because I used Poisson errors in my original model). Would it make sense to manually backtransform and simply graph those values with SE in another program?

In short, am I taking the appropriate direction and any hints on resources? 
I would much appreciate advice or direction to a tutorial/book/website for novices that could help.

Comment: "How to visualize your data in a way that is relevant to hypotheses and fits the model results" with a GLMM is a good question. But be careful, asking for code is off topic here. It is fine to have your data & code here for reference, but you don't want to convey the impression that your Q is just about how to use R, or a request for code.

Comment: understood, when I posted this in stackoverflow I got sent here! Just editted to eliminate code related questions.

Comment: You CAN get back-transformed values. Just add `type = "response")` to the call. And the `lsmip` function or `plot` method may give you what you need to visualize the results.